# Boolean Java program to check if k-clique in my graph "W"

Tags: java, backtracking

I am using the backtracking algorithm to write a program that checks if I have a k-clique in my graph `W` (`W` is a 2D array).

k-clique means that there exist k-vertices, in my graph `W`, such that every vertex is connected (form an edge) to all other (k-1) vertices. For instance, we say that v1, v2, and v3 form 3-clique if there is an edge between:

- `v1` and `v2`.
- `v1` and `v3`.
- `v1` and `v4`.
- `v2` and `v3`.
- `v2` and `v4`.
- `v3` and `v4`.

I.e., there exist an edge between `v1` and `v2` if `W[v1][v2] == 1`.

```
boolean haskclique(int n, int k, int [][] W){
            int[] kVertices = new int [k + 1];
            return haskcliqueRec(n, k, 0, kVertices, W);        
        }

public static boolean 
haskcliqueRec(int n, int k, int i, int [] kVertices, int W[][]){
              boolean hasKclique = true;

              if (i == k) {
                    //check if kCLique
                    for ( int x = 1; x <= k; x++){
                        int y = x + 1;
                        while (hasKclique && y <= k){
                            if( W[ kVertices[x] ][ kVertices[y] ] != 1 )
                                hasKclique = false;

                            if ( y == k && hasKclique)
                                return true;
                            y++;
                        }   
                    }
              }
              else{
                  for (kVertices[1] = W[1][1]; kVertices[1] <= k; kVertices[1]++)  
                   {
                      kVertices[i+1] = W[1][1];

                      //Check if there is a repeat
                      if( kVertices[i+1] != kVertices[i] )
                          haskcliqueRec(n, k, i+1, kVertices, W);
                   }
              }
              return false;
          }
```

I am getting `true` when my method should return `false`. Why?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't understand your example, for a 3-clique it would be enough to connect 1----2, 2----3 and 3----1. The else part in your rec function makes no sense. `kVertices[1] = W[1]1[1]` sets `kVertices[1]` to 0 or 1 depending if there is an edge from 1 to 1. I think you want to store the index of a vertice in `kVertices`?

Comment: For what instance do you get `true` instead of `false`? Did you try debugging what your code does and how it comes to its conclusion?